# How To Build an API URL using Postman Chrome extension

Tags: ios, json, postman

Currently interning in a mobile dev company. 
Working on a task that they assigned to me. 
Need to build an explore screen that receives JSON data. 
They have their JSON data coming through Postman chrome extension. 
I have authorization token and sample username/password. 
As well as something that looks like a link that I can modify:

https://nameoftheapp.nameofthecompany.com/api/v1/search/surveys/app?searchCategory=explore&limit=10&offset=0&location=global

All iOS json tutorials shows that I need an API url. 
How Can I build such URL?

edit: 
here is what I've been given - the Postman chrome extension: 
(sorry, had to hide some details because of non disclosure agreement)
[image]

Comment: All Postman does is make the request for you. You must have some path or API Url to be getting data back from something. Where are you making the request to?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Postman is just a extension that makes a request to some API url. Are you trying to make a request to a url using the URL above?

Comment: I was instructed step by step how to see the jSON data. But wasn't told how everything works. So I'm sharing what I have. A postman extension, a collection of mobile app apis (on the right sidebar), that link that I shared that shows up in the area to the right when I click on API i have to use, authorization token.

Comment: sorry, in the right sidebar i have a collection of requests.

Comment: I guess I am confused on what exactly you need to do? are you supposed to be building the api? So then maybe they just gave you the url as an example of how they want it formatted? otherwise does the api already exist and you need to build an app that hits it?

Comment: If possible can you please post a snapshot and describe it again ?

Comment: @Ellery sounds like you are right - the api is already there and it spits out JSONs dictionaries. And I need to display that json on one of view controllers. Based on Ray Wenderlich tutorials on JSON and API- I need an an api url to do that.

Comment: that field to the left of the dropdown menu that says GET is the api url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman assist you in testing the functionality you have built into an API. These functionalities can be accessed by typing in the URL and then using the GET, POST, PUT etc HTTP requests.

I think maybe this video can assist you in learning more about Postman - Javabrains does a great job at explaining it:

http://javabrains.koushik.org/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Installing-A-Rest-Api-Client